# JOIN and CASE duplicating Query results

Tags: sql, select, join, case, teradata

I am working with two tables within Teradata and I am trying to query every active item by store number, Total Days To Sell and total days within each store number.  My current Query setup is providing two rows of data by SKU instead of supplying one row that shows the appropriate information.

Table 1: Shows class number, class name, status and store data.

```
Store   Item    Class Number    Class Name         Status
100     Apple      10            Red Fruit         Active
200     Apple      10            Red Fruit         Active
100     Banana     12            Yellow Fruit      Active
200     Banana     12            Yellow Fruit      Active
100     Pear       14            Green Fruit       Active
200     Pear       14            Green Fruit       Active
100     Beans      20            Green Vegetable   Discontinued
200     Beans      20            Green Vegetable   Active
```

Table 2: Shows Total days to sell by store and item

```
Store   Item    Total Days to sell
100     Apple         4
200     Apple         1
100     Banana        2
200     Banana        4
100     Pear          3
200     Pear          6
100     Beans        NULL
200     Beans         4
```

Table 3: Current Query results

```
Item  Class Number   Class Name  Total Days to sell  Store 100   Store 200
Apple     10         Red Fruit           5               4         NULL
Apple     10         Red Fruit           5              NULL        1
Banana    12         Yellow Fruit        6               2         NULL
Banana    12         Yellow Fruit        6              NULL        4
Pear      14         Green Fruit         9               3         NULL
Pear      14         Green Fruit         9              NULL        6
Beans     20         Green Vegetable     4              NULL        4
```

Below is How I am looking for the data to be organized:

```
Item    Class Number    Class Name  Total Days to sell  Store 100   Store 200
Apple     10             Red Fruit          5              4           1
Banana    12             Yellow Fruit       6              2           4
Pear      14             Green Fruit        9              3           6
Beans     20             Green Vegetable    4             NULL         4
```

Current Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT     
    A.ITEM, 
    A.CLASS_NUMBER, 
    A.CLASS_NAME,   
    SUM(B.TOTAL_DAYS_TO_SELL),  
    CASE    
        WHEN B.STORE=100 THEN B.TOTAL_DAYS_TO_SELL
        ELSE NULL
        END AS STORE 100,
    CASE    
        WHEN B.STORE=200 THEN B.TOTAL_DAYS_TO_SELL
        ELSE NULL
        END AS STORE 200
FROM TABLE 1 A      
RIGHT JOIN TABLE 2 B        
ON B.ITEM=A.ITEM        
WHERE A.STATUS='ACTIVE'     
GROUP BY        
    A.ITEM, 
    A.CLASS_NUMBER, 
    A.CLASS_NAME,   
    STORE 100,  
    STORE 200   
ORDER BY        
    A.CLASS_NUMBER ASC;
```

Please let me know if you have any questions regarding the information

Thanks!

Comment: Stick a `Sum()` around those last two case statements and take them out of your group by.

Comment: the functions around the case statements fixed the duplicated rows, but the Total Days to sell is now doubled.  Is this fixable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT A.ITEM, A.CLASS_NUMBER, A.CLASS_NAME, SUM(B.TOTAL_DAYS_TO_SELL),  
       SUM(CASE WHEN B.STORE = 100 THEN B.TOTAL_DAYS_TO_SELL END) as STORE_100,
       SUM(CASE WHEN B.STORE = 200 THEN B.TOTAL_DAYS_TO_SELL END) as STORE_200
FROM TABLE1 A JOIN     
     TABLE2 B        
     ON B.ITEM = A.ITEM        
WHERE A.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'     
GROUP BY A.ITEM, A.CLASS_NUMBER, A.CLASS_NAME
ORDER BY A.CLASS_NUMBER ASC;
```

This is essentially Lamak's answer, but with more editorial:

- Don't use `SELECT DISTINCT` unless you really know what you are doing.  It is almost never appropriate with `GROUP BY`.
- You have three columns that are not being aggregated; those should be the ones in the `GROUP BY`.
- Your `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is being turned into an `INNER JOIN` by the `WHERE` clause.  Just use `INNER JOIN`.  Further, you are aggregating by columns in `A`.  Do you really want aggregation columns that are `NULL`?
- The `ELSE` clause is not needed on the `CASE`, because the default is `NULL`.
- This version chooses `SUM()` for the aggregation.  With one numeric value, `SUM()`, `MIN()`, and `MAX()` all return the same things.  But, I think `SUM()` is safer in case you want to remove some aggregation keys.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed bullet points, very helpful!  The MAX function around the case statements helped, but now the Total Days to Sell column is being doubled.  For instance: Apple shows 10 Total days when the answer should be 5.  Is it doubling because there are two stores?

Comment: @Hery0502 . . . Yes, that would be why it is doubled.  I'm not sure what you want to do with the value . . . perhaps `AVG()` is appropriate?

Comment: I will remove the Total Days to Sell column and just add store 100 & 200 columns as a grand total column.  Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, no need for `DISTINCT`, since you are using `GROUP BY`.

For the result that you want, you need to use an aggregation function on the `CASE` expressions that you are using. From the data that you showed, you could use `MIN`, `MAX` or `SUM` (even `AVG`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT     
    A.ITEM, 
    A.CLASS_NUMBER, 
    A.CLASS_NAME,   
    SUM(B.TOTAL_DAYS_TO_SELL),  
    MIN(CASE    
            WHEN B.STORE=100 THEN B.TOTAL_DAYS_TO_SELL
            ELSE NULL
         END) AS STORE 100,
    MIN(CASE    
            WHEN B.STORE=200 THEN B.TOTAL_DAYS_TO_SELL
            ELSE NULL
        END) AS STORE 200
FROM TABLE 1 A      
RIGHT JOIN TABLE 2 B        
ON B.ITEM=A.ITEM        
WHERE A.STATUS='ACTIVE'     
GROUP BY        
    A.ITEM, 
    A.CLASS_NUMBER, 
    A.CLASS_NAME
ORDER BY        
    A.CLASS_NUMBER ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you, Lamak!  The MAX around the case statement helped aggregate the values into one row, but the Total Days to sell is now doubling.  For example: Apple is showing 10 when the answer is 5, how can I fix this?